# Why is every sequential map uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

This statement puzzles me.

> Prove that *every* map $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous.

Can someone give me a quick argument for this? I just know that $f$ on integer domains will get out of any discontinuity situation.

Comment: Think about how you proved that every such $f$ was at least continuous. For each $n$ and $\epsilon$ you had to produce a $\delta$. Did $\delta$ have much to do with the particular $f$, $n$, or $\epsilon$? If your $\delta$ wasn't extremely greedy, probably not.

Comment: @Hoot, I didn't write down anything rigorous like that. That idea just occurred to me after drawing some pictures. Because since I will have discrete points on the plane, I can't get discontinuity.

Comment: I think it would be good to figure out how to prove continuity first. Anyway, it looks like someone has done the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $x\in\mathbb{N}$, we have $|y-x|< 1/2,y\in\mathbb{N}\implies y=x\implies|f(y)-f(x)|=0$

**Edit** By definition, $f: \Bbb N \to \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous if $\forall\epsilon>0 \exists\delta>0$ such that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{N}$, $|y-x|<\delta\implies|f(y)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. But $\delta=1/2$ works, because $\forall\epsilon>0\forall x,y\in\mathbb{N}$, $|y-x|<1/2\implies y=x\implies |f(y)-f(x)|=0<\epsilon$.

Comment: Why is $\delta = 1/2$?

Comment: Any $\delta$ less than 1 works.

Comment: Less than $1/2$, rather.

Comment: I know any $\delta < 1$ works. I thought we have to know something about $f$ before we can select $\delta$.